# Create Previous, Next Buttons in FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

can someone help me to add buttons for Previous Next and pages between them.

For example in my FlowLayoutPanel1 it display 4 results, because i do not want to use autoscroll=true

what i want to do is after the 4th results by pressing button to continue to next records display in the flowlayoutpanel and so one.

What i mean is to create outside the flowlayout buttons Previous,1,2,3,4,Next buttons that when click to do action inside the flowlayoutpanel

[Demo Buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPt95.png)

Something like that i would like to create

Here is my code for add stuff in the layoutpanel

```
Private Sub GenerateDynamicUserControl()
    FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear()
    Dim dt As DataTable = New ClassBLL().GetItems()

    If dt IsNot Nothing Then

        If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            Dim listItems As ListItem() = New ListItem(dt.Rows.Count - 1) {}

            For i As Integer = 0 To 1 - 1

                For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
                    Dim listItem As New ListItem()
                    listItems(i) = listItem
                    'Dim ms As New MemoryStream(CType(row("userPic"), Byte()))
                    listItems(i).Width = FlowLayoutPanel1.Width
                    listItems(i).Icon = orderPicFromString
                    listItems(i).Icon2 = orderPicFromString2
                    listItems(i).OrderFrom = row("orderacc").ToString()
                    listItems(i).OrderTitle = row("orderfrom").ToString()
                    listItems(i).OrderReceiver = row("orderreceiveracc").ToString()
                    listItems(i).OrderTitle2 = row("orderreceiver").ToString()
                    'listItems(i).ButtonBackground = orderButtonBackString
                    listItems(i).ButtonText = row("orderstatus").ToString()
                    listItems(i).OrderDate = row("orderdate")
                    listItems(i).IDOrder = row("orderid").ToString()

                    If listItems(i).ButtonText = "Accepted" Then
                        listItems(i).ButtonBackground = Color.FromArgb(26, 168, 92)
                    ElseIf listItems(i).ButtonText = "Declined" Then
                        listItems(i).ButtonBackground = Color.FromArgb(246, 50, 90)
                    ElseIf listItems(i).ButtonText = "Proceed" Then
                        listItems(i).ButtonBackground = Color.FromArgb(255, 174, 33)
                    ElseIf listItems(i).ButtonText = "Waiting" Then
                        listItems(i).ButtonBackground = Color.FromArgb(53, 121, 255)
                    Else
                        listItems(i).ButtonBackground = Color.FromArgb(91, 146, 255)
                    End If
                    FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(listItems(i))
                Next
            Next
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

And the code that calls the read of database MS Access DB is like this:

```
Public Function ReadItemsTable() As DataTable
    Using cons As New OleDbConnection(ServerStatus)
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand()
            cmd.Connection = cons
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM OrdersAssigned ORDER BY ID ASC"
            cons.Open()
            Using sda As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
                Dim dt As New DataTable()
                sda.Fill(dt)
                Return dt
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Function

Public Function GetItems() As DataTable
    Try
        Dim objdal As New ClassDAL()
        Return objdal.ReadItemsTable()
    Catch e As Exception
        Dim result As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show(e.Message.ToString())
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: It's not really that clear to me exactly what you're intending to do with these previous/next buttons.  Do you want to for example click next, remove all the content of the FLP, then query the db to get the next set of content and build it dynamically?

Comment: in flowlayoutpanel autoscroll = false
so it display 4 results in size, i want with buttons to show next results after the first 4 were showed

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not getting it.  What is supposed to happen to the existing content when you click the next button?  Are you intending to remove it and recreate new content or append the new content to the bottom or something?  As a little aside, what is the point of the listItems array, seems to serve 0 purpose as you can work directly on the instance of ListItem()

Comment: `For i As Integer = 0 To 1 - 1` Why would you write a loop the runs once?

Comment: You have a DataTable. Why are you messing with an array of ListItems?

Comment: FlowLayoutPanel right? So this would be WinForms. Then I get to ListItem and that seems to be an ASP class. What kind of app is this?

Comment: this is WinForm , listitems(i) will display results from database to layoutpanel that is connected with user control